# Ember JS: Child route needs to render in a higher level outlet, removing its direct ancestor

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Here is my current router:

```
Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('portal', function() {
        this.resource('placements', function() {
            this.resource('add-debtor', function() {
                this.route('debtor-form');
            });
            this.route('import-debtors');
            this.resource('view-debtors', function() {
                this.resource('debtor', function() {
                    this.route('debt-summary');
                    this.route('agent-notes');
                    this.route('transactions');
                });
            });
        });
        this.route('admin');
    });
});
```

I have a tricky situation that is causing me some stress at the moment.

One of my leaf most resources ("debtor") has a vastly different template structure, which is requiring me to have it render into a higher level outlet... essentially breaking out of the nested template scheme I currently have.

my "potal" template's outlet is the target.  I named the outlet `{{outlet portal}}` and I attempted the following, according to [Ember Routing Guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/rendering-a-template/):

```
// --routes/debtor.js

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    renderTemplate: function() {
        this.render({ outlet: 'portal' });
    }
});
```

This does not work however... when attempting to transition into the debtor route, the result is that the view-debtors template gets rendered instead.  THere is not outlet in that particular template, so it ends there.

I think what needs to happen is, Ember needs to tear down the templates that are directly above the "debtor" route ("view-debtor" and "placements") before rendering into the "portal" template.

This is going beyond my current knowledge of Ember, an I am a little worried that it might not be possible.

I can't modify the router, because that is the URL structure that is required.

Looking for some suggestions or some workaround.

Comment: Did your try to add the `into` property which is the last example at docs your mentioned?

Comment: well, that did the trick.  wow. Apparently I can just tell ember to render a template `into` another template... I didn't need to name the outlet after all.  thanks!